# Aggregate columns with same date (sum) in csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

My code is returning the following data in CSV

```
Quantity    Date of purchase
1   17 May 2022 at 5:40:20PM BST
1   2 Apr 2022 at 7:41:29PM BST
1   2 Apr 2022 at 6:42:05PM BST
1   29 Mar 2022 at 12:34:56PM BST
1   29 Mar 2022 at 10:52:54AM BST
1   29 Mar 2022 at 12:04:52AM BST
1   28 Mar 2022 at 4:49:34PM BST
1   28 Mar 2022 at 11:13:37AM BST
1   27 Mar 2022 at 8:53:05PM BST
1   27 Mar 2022 at 5:10:21PM BST
```

I am trying to get the dates only and adding the quantity data with the same date but below is the code for that

```
data = read_csv("products_sold_history_data.csv")
data['Date of purchase'] = pandas.to_datetime(data['Date of purchase'] , format='%d-%m-%Y').dt.date
```

but its giving me error can anyone please help how can I take the dates only from Date of purchase column and then add the quantity values in the same date.

Comment: Try to minimize the post, a few of lines of data is enough to understand the pattern and also, format your code so it can be viewed without scrolling right

Comment: Also please show the error you get.

Comment: @IanS this is the error AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it, where a date is created as a on-fly field and not making part of the DF.

Also, IIUC you're not concerned with the time part and only date is what you need to use for summing it up

extract the date part using regex, create a temp field dte using pandas.assign, and then a groupby to sum up the quantity

```
df.assign(dte = pd.to_datetime(
    df['purchase'].str.extract(r'(.*)(at)')[0].str.strip())
    ).groupby('dte')['qty'].sum().reset_index()
```

```
    dte        qty
0   2022-02-06  3
1   2022-02-07  3
2   2022-02-08  2
3   2022-02-09  2
4   2022-02-10  2
5   2022-02-11  3
6   2022-02-14  1
7   2022-02-15  1
8   2022-02-19  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Date format in your data is not the format that you specified: `format='%d-%m-%Y'`.

You could specify it explicitly, or let pandas infer the format for you by not providing the format:

```
pandas.to_datetime(data['Date of purchase']).dt.date
```

If you want to specify the format explicitly, you should provide the format that matches your data:

```
pandas.to_datetime(data['Date of purchase'], format='%d %b %Y at %H:%M:%S%p %Z')
```

Comment: its giving the error: ValueError: time data '17 May 2022 at 5:40:20PM BST' does not match format '%d %b %Y at %H:%M:%S%p %Z'

Comment: @MHusnainAliNasir `BST` is not a valid timezone in pandas.

Comment: so should I remove it by regular expressions?